# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "postgres" to address: nodename nor servname provided

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, fastapi, alembic

I am following a [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sOvCWFmrtA&t=53s) to create an API using FastAPI. I am new to both Docker and FastAPI. I have managed to create a Docker container for the API and another one for the Postgres database using this Dockerfile and docker-compose:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.7

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports: 
      - 80:8000
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app.ro
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    command: bash -c "uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload"

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    volumes:
      - postgres-db:/var/lib/posgresql/data 
volumes:
  postgres-db:
```

I am also using Alembic, so after setting up both containers, I run

```
docker-compose run api alembic upgrade head
```

in order to create the corresponding tables.

Everything runs smoothly when testing with Postman. I can run GET and POST queries that interact with the database and the are no issues. The problem comes when trying to test the API code using TestClient from FastAPI. I am running two tests:

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from app.main import app

client = TestClient(app)

def test_root():
    response = client.get("/")
    assert response.json().get('message') == "Welcome to my API"
    assert response.status_code == 200


def test_create_user():
    response = client.post("/users/", json = {"email": "hashed_email1222@gmail.com", "password": "test"})
    assert response.status_code == 201
```

The first one passes without a problem, but the second one fails with the following error message:

```
FAILED tests/test_users.py::test_create_user - sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "postgres" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Since there are no issues when testing using Postman, I am not sure if there are any configurations that need to be set in order to use TestClient.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Are you running your tests in docker? The `postgres` hostname is only available inside the docker network. If you are running your tests outside of docker, you should connect on ``localhost:5432` instead.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am running the tests locally, from my project folder. What I cant understand is how HTTP POST requests made from Postman (also locally) work fine, but the same POST request made with TestClient from FastAPI throws the mentioned error. The test does not try to access the Postgres database directly, that is performed by the api instance and works perfectly fine when the request is made from Postman.

Answer (score 0):

You should install pytest-env and add a pytest.ini with the following conf:

[pytest]
env =
DB_URL=postgresql+psycopg2://user:pass@localhost/dbname

Please change DB_URL (env variable name), user, pass and dbname for your actual values.